# RS232 serial communication in flutter

Tags: flutter, serial-port

I want to establish a connection between RS232 with flutter can anyone have knowledge how to do this?can any one have source code of this?

Answer (score 0):

You find various extension packages for exactly this on pub.dev: https://pub.dev/packages?q=serial

I have successfully used some USB to serial adapters on Android in the past.

Good luck with you project!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a flutter plugin for serial communication
on a pub.dev: https://pub.dev/packages/serial_communication

if you call the method
serialCommunication.getAvailablePorts();
It returns the available ports on the device
if you have an rs232 port available then call startserial() method in init.
Further, run the example code.
I hope it may help
Thanks